# How to pass array of strings in query api rspec tests using rswag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, swagger

I need to test search api endpoint - search users by skills.
When I trying to find user in app frontend, I see this params in console:

`Processing by UsersController#search as JSON
  Parameters: {"tags"=>["rails"]}`

How can I correctly pass array of string from the test to the api endpoint?

Here is the integration test code:

```
  path '/api/users/search' do
    post 'search users' do
      tags 'Users'
      security [apiKey: []]
      consumes 'application/json'
      produces 'application/json'

      parameter name: :tags,
                in: :query,
                type: :array,
                example: %w(angular ruby)

      response '200', 'Returns users' do
        let(:logged_user) { User.find_by(email: 'admin@company.name') }
        let(:skill) { create :skill }
        let(:skill2) { create :skill }
        let(:tags) do
          [skill.title, skill2.title]
        end
        let(:user) { create :user }

        before do
          user.skills << skill
          user.skills << skill2
        end

        run_test!
      end

    end
  end
```

When I run this test, I getting error:

```
  1) User resource /api/users/search post Returns users returns a 200 response
     Failure/Error:
       params.dig(:tags).each do |tag|
         skills.concat(Skill.where(
           "title ilike '#{tag}' or variants ~* '(^#{tag}|[\s,]#{tag})(,|$)'"
         ).pluck(:id))
       end

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for "aut,iste":String
```

But I can't find anything in the gem docs that can help me to solve it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, have already tried this. its reproduces new error: ` `NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'split' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x0000563bf656eec8>`.
Also I need to say that in app (not in tests) it works fine without split

Comment: Uh; ok, then it seems to be somewhat Rails-specific; let’s see if any Rails guru answers this.

Comment: Can you try running the test with a string, instead of array for tags (leave the param setting as array) `let(:tags) { "#{skill.title},#{skill2.title}"}`? I'm using `type: :array` in my codebase and have no issues, but I'm using jsonapi-resources which handles the params parsing for me.

Comment: @JayDorsey, got `undefined method 'each' for "minus,molestias":String`. After that If I try to use split - I got the same undefined method error as I wrote in the first comment

Comment: When you say split, you mean you've tried doing `params.dig(:tags).split(',').each do |tag|`?

Comment: @JayDorsey yes. I tried this after using your advice and getting undefined method each for string error.

Comment: Maybe you should use a let bang here `let(:tags)` ?

Comment: @morissetcl didn't understand your answer. what do you mean? I have already use `let(:tags)` in my test code. sorry for my English

Comment: There's an open issue about this: https://github.com/rswag/rswag/issues/256